# zsh: bindkey to only bind spaces not working

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, key-binding

I run this command in my zsh: `bindkey -s '  ' 'ls\n'` and it was working nicely, when I press space twice, the `ls` command is executed. But when I add the exact same line to my `.zshrc` it does not recognice the two spaces as a key binding.
What am I doing wrong? I also use `oh-my-zsh`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the key binding is in fact defined in the shell after adding it to `~/.zshrc`? That is, what does `bindkey '  '` return?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I sourced `oh-my-zsh.sh` after the bindkey command. After doing this before my bindkey commands, everything works.